# region selection

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, cookies

I'm developing a website, where the visitor has to choose it's region Europe / Asia, according to this choice the menu should be different, (most pages are the same).

When I would develop this in any other environment my choice would be to put the selection in a cookie, and check the cookie in my templates.

Is there another, better way to do this in wordpress? 
Also I think a nice way to do it would be to just put it in my .htaccess.

So it would be `example.com/asia/aboutus` and `example.com/europe/aboutus`.

The problem is I am also using qtranslate, so I might screw that up it would be, `/asia/en/aboutus`. So can I have this in my permalinks?

---

EDIT

I have tried this method ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256888/how-to-include-a-custom-string-in-a-wordpress-permalink )  and adapted it to my needs. But it doesn't seem to work.
Can someone find my mistake? Thanks a lot.
What happens now when i go to website.com/en/asia/about-us it changes into website.com/en/about-us and nothing else happens.

**tldr**: I have, website.com/en/about-us and I want, website.com/en/asia/about-us
so I can get 'asia' in my page, to change my menu accordingly.

My code in functions.php

```
function my_rewrite_rules($rules)
{
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // the key is a regular expression
    // the value maps matches into a query string
    $my_rule = array(
        '(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=matches[3]&my_action=$matches[2]&lang=$matches[1]'
    );

    return array_merge($my_rule, $rules);
}
add_filter('page_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules');


function my_query_vars($vars)
{
    // this value should match the rewrite rule query paramter above

    // I recommend using something more unique than 'action', as you
    // could collide with other plugins or WordPress core

    $my_vars = array('my_action');
    return array_merge($my_vars, $vars);
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars');
```

my code in index.php

```
echo esc_html(get_query_var('my_action'));
```

My .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  AddType video/ogg .ogv
  AddType video/webm .webm
  AddType video/mp4 .mp4
</IfModule>
```

Comment: These are pretty old code snippets you pulled out. Adding rewrite rules has its own API nowadays - see Codex.

Comment: oh ok. I'll check it out . Find it weird no-one can give me a straight solution, I'ld figure this has to be used quite often...

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought:

Append your link/URL a query arg with [`add_query_arg`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.2/wp-includes/functions.php#L638).

Then extract it on load and reroute using `exit( wp_redirect( home_url( '/etc' ) );` or whatever fits you best.

Comment: ok, that would work for one link. But I need the selection throughout the whole website then. So I would have to add_query to all my links? also for example, wp_nav_menu. 
or how do I make sure I keep my query arg then ?

Comment: that didn't help me I need it in a 'pretty' links way. See my original question adapted